# is there a way to colspan and rowspan in plsql spool into .csv?

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, spool

is it possible to rowspan and colspan on .csv using spool? Like how you use a rospan and colspan in html <table< tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the CSV format does not support data points spanning multiple rows and columns.

---

[RFC 4180: Common Format and MIME Type for CSV Files](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) defines a CSV as:

> This section documents the format that seems to be followed by most implementations:
>
> 1. Each record is located on a separate line, delimited by a line
>    break (CRLF).  For example:
>
>    ```
>    aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx CRLF
>    ```
> 2. The last record in the file may or may not have an ending line
>    break.  For example:
>
>    ```
>    aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx
>    ```
> 3. There maybe an optional header line appearing as the first line
>    of the file with the same format as normal record lines.  This
>    header will contain names corresponding to the fields in the file
>    and should contain the same number of fields as the records in
>    the rest of the file (the presence or absence of the header line
>    should be indicated via the optional "header" parameter of this
>    MIME type).  For example:
>
>    ```
>    field_name,field_name,field_name CRLF
>    aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx CRLF
>    ```
> 4. Within the header and each record, there may be one or more
>    fields, separated by commas.  Each line should contain the same
>    number of fields throughout the file.  Spaces are considered part
>    of a field and should not be ignored.  The last field in the
>    record must not be followed by a comma.  For example:
>
>    ```
>    aaa,bbb,ccc
>    ```
> 5. Each field may or may not be enclosed in double quotes (however
>    some programs, such as Microsoft Excel, do not use double quotes
>    at all).  If fields are not enclosed with double quotes, then
>    double quotes may not appear inside the fields.  For example:
>
>    ```
>    "aaa","bbb","ccc" CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx
>    ```
> 6. Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
>    should be enclosed in double-quotes.  For example:
>
>    ```
>    "aaa","b CRLF
>    bb","ccc" CRLF
>    zzz,yyy,xxx
>    ```
> 7. If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
>    appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
>    another double quote.  For example:
>
>    ```
>    "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
>    ```

There is no mention of implementing `rowspan` or `colspan` or even of the concept of fields spanning multiple rows or columns.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I'd like to ask again is there a way to do it? it doesn't have to be .csv , as long as it can be opened in Ms excel.

Comment: @AlecLucero If you want to ask a different question then [ask a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).